# Проверка на количество активных использований команды

Tags: python, discord.py

Как сделать проверку на количество активных использований команды? !give код(random.randint(100,999)), при каждом запуске бота - идет генерация кода и количество использований и все записывается в файл (допустим 0/1) и при активации команды было 1/1. Работа с файлом json (100 1/1)